# Performing session management in python

Tags: python, session, extjs

I have created an application in python. And I am using extjs for the front-end.
Once a valid user logs in, I want to use the username of the logged in user for further transactions.
I wanted urgent help on how session management is to be done in python. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's done with a web framework.  Which framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You don't do "session management in Python". You do "session management in a framework, which may be implemented in Python".

A session can be implemented in many ways, but normally is implemented via Cookies. For example, Django (a Python framework), writes a cookie with a value called `session` containing a given string (say `aabbccddeeff12345`). For every request, Django checks whether the cookie exists, and if it does, it maps it to a user.

This is far from trivial. However, if you use Django (or most robust web frameworks in **any** language), this is completely transparent.

If you don't know what a cookie is, or are unfamiliar with web security, I don't think this is a problem that you should tackle yourself.

Use a framework, and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a framework or if your framework doesn't provide session management, Beaker is a popular library do this.

Examples at https://beaker.groovie.org/sessions.html#using show how to store a username in the session object.